# Need to find and delete a string from multiple files

Tags: sed, base64, findstr

One of my websites has been hit with a malware attack. I downloaded the entire server to my computer and need to find all the files that have a specific string in them, remove that string, and save the files again. 
This code has successfully located all the files with the string, but I can't get any further.

```
FINDSTR /s /i /m base64 *.*
```

Although the full string I need to remove is much longer. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "This code has...". Which code?

Comment: did you search here or on related site http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ? This is a very common question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you planning your site to be hit with the same issue again?

Otherwise just use any text editor that supports "find and replace in files" (our Visual Studio supports it for all editions including Express) and perform it once. Use regular expression to find whole string somthing like "base64[^;]+".

Comment: I can do that, although hundreds of files are infected, and I need to do it in one command.

Comment: Whatever works for you. It is still just one button click ("Replace All") in Visual Studio for **all** files, I think most other editors will require one click too.

Comment: Understood. Is there any way to do it without opening all the files first? Opening that many files at once could kill my computer.
Thanks by the way.

Comment: Thank you. Using dreamweaver in the find and replace menu, I was un-aware that there was an option to apply the command to a whole folder. Makes my life a lot easier.